# Angular JS select with manual options

Tags: javascript, angularjs

We have some drop downs in our app that we can **NOT** use **ng-options** with because we need to set the title attribute on the <options> tag itself which is not possible with **ng-options**.

*The reason we need the title is because IE < 9 chops off values that are to long and they are only visible with the title(shows up on hover of the element)*

Now, to see the issue I'm having look at the following JS fiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/nstuart/nF7eJ/
(HTML Bit)

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <select ng-model="params.value">
        <option value="">Any</option>
        <option ng-repeat="v in options" value="{{v.value}}" title="{{v.name}}" ng-selected="{{v.value == params.value}}">{{v.name}}</option>
    </select>
    <p>{{params.value}}</p>
</div>
```

Ideally the **select** would have 'test3' selected, but you can see it gets set to an empty option instead. I understand this is from the fact that the value of ng-model is not present in the **ng-options**, but thats because I have not defined one!

Any ideas on how to get something like this working? Possibly even be able to add title to the options generated by ng-options so we could use that instead?

**EDIT**

Updated the fiddle at: http://jsfiddle.net/nstuart/nBphn/2/ to as described in the answer below.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Actually, just remove the curly braces from the expression in ng-selected and it will work:

```
<option ng-repeat="v in options" 
        value="{{v.value}}" 
        title="{{v.name}}" 
        ng-selected="v.value == params.value">{{v.name}}
</option>
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nF7eJ/11/)

Comment: Gaahhhh! Thanks, that was it. I've updated the fiddle so it works. It still adds the weird empty <option> at the top, but that goes away when something is selected.

Answer (score 1):

```
<option ng-repeat="v in options" value="{{v.value}}" title="{{v.name}}"
        ng-selected="checkOption(v.value)">{{v.name}}</option>

$scope.checkOption = function(value){
    return($scope.params.value == value);
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bfelda/nF7eJ/10/)

[UPDATE] forgot to pass value variable.  Updated fiddle and answer.

Comment: Take a look at my answer. `ngSelected` takes an expression as its argument. That comment on the docs page is incorrect. In your answer here `checkOption(v.value)` is a String that is evaluated by Angular as an expression in the current scope. So expressions are just fine.

Comment: Accepted satchmorun's answer as it's more technically correct. You just leave off the {{}} and it will take a function or a regular == check. Thanks though Ben, was in the right direction and would have fixed it as well.

Comment: @nick.stuart I couldn't agree more.  I had a doh! moment after reading satchmorun's answer as well.

Answer (score 1):

For manual options, you only need to use `ng-model` directive. This `ng-model` directive gives two way data binding for the selected option.

jsfiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/rpaul/1p9b5et8/1/

```
<body ng-app ng-controller="AppCtrl">
<select ng-model="selectedFruit" >
    <option value ='1'> Apple</option>
     <option value ='2'> Orange</option>
</select>
   Selected value is  {{selectedFruit}}
</body>


function AppCtrl($scope) {     

      $scope.selectedFruit = '1';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might also want to take a look at the select2 directive in http://angular-ui.github.com/#directives-select2

Answer (score 0):

In my code, I re-calculate select title on ng-change="changeItem()"

HTML

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <select ng-options="item.id as item.title for item in items" 
            ng-model="selectedId" ng-change="changeItem()" title="{{myTitle}}">
        <option value="" disabled selected style="display: none;">Select Item</option>                
    </select>
    <div>
        {{selectedId}}        
    </div>
    <div>
        {{myTitle}}        
    </div>
</div>
```

app.js

```
angular.module('myApp', []);

function MyCtrl($scope) {

    $scope.items = [{
        id: 1,
        title: "Icebox"
    }, {
        id: 2,
        title: "Summer"
    }, {
        id: 3,
        title: "Milestone"
    }];

    $scope.changeItem = function() {
        $scope.myTitle = undefined;
        for(var i=0; i<$scope.items.length; i++){
            if($scope.items[i].id == $scope.selectedId){
                $scope.myTitle = $scope.items[i].title;    
            }
        }    
    }    
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ncG5s/8/)