# Why is Angular not selecting the correct select option by default?

Tags: angularjs

We have a Select tag like this:

```
<select id="nonemployeeSelect"
        ng-model="data.nonEmployeeCase.nonEmployeeId">
    <option ng-repeat="nonemployee in data.nonemployees"
            ng-value={{nonemployee.id}} ng-selected="{{nonemployee.id == @ViewBag.nonempId}}">
        {{nonemployee.organization.displayValue}}
    </option>
</select>
```

ng-model binds to a property initialized in an Angular controller like this:

```
$scope.data.nonEmployeeCase = {};
$scope.data.nonEmployeeCase.nonEmployeeId = 1;
```

ng-repeat is from an array of nonEmployees on the scope:

```
$scope.data.nonemployees
```

So the html for the select ends up looking like this:

```
 <select id="nonemployeeSelect" ng-model="data.nonEmployeeCase.nonEmployeeId" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-not-empty">
        <!-- ngRepeat: nonemployee in data.nonemployees --><option ng-repeat="nonemployee in data.nonemployees" ng-value="1" ng-selected="false" class="ng-binding ng-scope" value="number:1" selected="selected">
            Office of the Administrator
        </option><!-- end ngRepeat: nonemployee in data.nonemployees --><option ng-repeat="nonemployee in data.nonemployees" ng-value="2" ng-selected="false" class="ng-binding ng-scope" value="number:2">
            Office of Women’s Health
        </option><!-- end ngRepeat: nonemployee in data.nonemployees --><option ng-repeat="nonemployee in data.nonemployees" ng-value="3" ng-selected="true" class="ng-binding ng-scope" value="number:3">
            Office of Budget
        </option><!-- end ngRepeat: nonemployee in data.nonemployees --><option ng-repeat="nonemployee in data.nonemployees" ng-value="4" ng-selected="false" class="ng-binding ng-scope" value="number:4">
            Office of the Administrator
        </option><!-- end ngRepeat: nonemployee in data.nonemployees --><option ng-repeat="nonemployee in data.nonemployees" ng-value="5" ng-selected="false" class="ng-binding ng-scope" value="number:5">
            Division of Budget Execution and Management
        </option><!-- end ngRepeat: nonemployee in data.nonemployees --><option ng-repeat="nonemployee in data.nonemployees" ng-value="6" ng-selected="false" class="ng-binding ng-scope" value="number:6">
            Division of Program Budget Services
        </option><!-- end ngRepeat: nonemployee in data.nonemployees -->
    </select>
```

So in the above, the third option has "ng-selected == true" so our ng-selected expression is working correctly.

And we have ng-value from nonemployee.id giving us our ng-values (1,2,3,4,5,6).
And we have our ng-model binding to "data.nonEmployeeCase.nonEmployeeId" in the controller.
If I change the select option it updates the model value.  Great.

The problem is that the ng-value should be working ng-selected to select the correct expression right off the bat on load execution and update the model.  But it is not.  It is taking the model value from "data.nonEmployeeCase.nonEmployeeId" and using that to set the correct option to selected.

This has worked for me in other places but is not working here.
Does anyone see the problem?
Any ideas?

It just seems to be working in reverse.
Instead of ng-value and ng-selected working together to select the correct option tag and then update the model,  the model is initializing the selected option.  After that you can select another option and update the model.  That is great.  But we need to initialize going the other way.

Comment: Why don't you use ng-options? Is there any reason for that? or just you don't know about it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular JS select with manual options](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14900497/angular-js-select-with-manual-options)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why this method is not working for me like it does in other places. But I fixed it with an ng-init on the Option tag.

```
<select id="nonemployeeSelect" 
        ng-model="data.nonEmployeeCase.nonEmployeeId">
    <option ng-repeat="nonemployee in data.nonemployees"
            ng-init="nonemployee.id == @ViewBag.nonempId ? data.nonEmployeeCase.nonEmployeeId = nonemployee.id : null"
            ng-value={{nonemployee.id}}>
        {{nonemployee.organization.displayValue}}
    </option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

The documentation warns that `ng-selected` should not be used with the `select` directive and the `ng-model` directive.

> > **Note:** `ngSelected` does not interact with the `select` and `ngModel` directives, it only sets the `selected` attribute on the element. If you are using `ngModel` on the select, you should not use `ngSelected` on the options, as `ngModel` will set the select value and selected options.
>
> [— AngularJS ng-selected Directive API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSelected)

For more information, see

- [AngularJS Migration Guide (Migrating from 1.3 to 1.4 - select)](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/migration#select)
- [AngularJS Issue #14876 - [bug] ngSelected won't select the option within a ngRepeat](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/14876)
- [AngularJS Issue #14916 - `<select>` with `<option>` does not set default option correctly](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/14916)
- [AngularJS commit - docs(ngSelected): note that it doesn't interact with ngModel](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/cd06cccc7f41cd54e171b2ddba534ace1f36b1ff)